# ASP.NET CORE MVC SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_User'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'. The duplicate key valu

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

в модели Video есть два свойства:
`public string UserId { get; set; }`
`[ForeignKey("UserId")] public User User { get; set; }`
в модели User есть свойство, модель расширяет IdentityUser:
`public ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }`
при загрузке видео получаю ошибку SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_User'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'. The duplicate key value is (831769c6-fc01-4203-a345-0aa12702b95e)
код метода upload

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(VideoUploadViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);

        var video = new Video
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            Description = model.Description,
            DurationSeconds = model.DurationSeconds,
            CategoryId = model.CategoryId,
            User = user,
            UserId = userId
        };

        await _videoRepository.AddVideoAsync(video, model.VideoFile);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var categories = await _categoryRepository.GetAllCategoriesAsync();
    ViewBag.Categories = categories;

    return View(model);
}
```

userId получает созданного пользователя и user получает пользователя по Id
получается так: он пытается создать User по данным из поля User, а не просто связывает модели
код репозитория

```
public async Task AddVideoAsync(Video video, IFormFile videoFile)
{
    try
    {
        if (videoFile != null && videoFile.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(videoFile.FileName);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "videos", fileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await videoFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            video.FilePath = fileName;
        }

        _context.Videos.Add(video);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(video.FilePath))
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "videos", video.FilePath);
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

```
public class Video
{
    [Key]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Название видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Название видео")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Длина 'Названия' не должна превышать 100 символов")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Описание видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Описание видео")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Длина 'Описания' не должна превышать 500 символов")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Продолжительность видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Продолжительность видео")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Значение 'Продолжительность' должно быть неотрицательным")]
    public int DurationSeconds { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Файл видео")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Выберите видеофайл")]
    public IFormFile VideoFile { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Категория видео")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Категория видео' обязательно для заполнения")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<View> Views { get; set; }


    public Video()
    {
        UploadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Likes = new List<Like>();
        Views = new List<View>();
    }
}
```

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Email' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Некорректный формат 'Email'")]
    public override string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле 'Логин' обязательно для заполнения")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Длина 'Логина' должна быть от 3 до 50 символов")]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Дата регистрации")]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SearchHistory> SearchHistory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WatchHistory> WatchHistory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WatchLater> WatchLaterList { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    public ICollection<View> Views { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        RegistrationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Videos = new List<Video>();
        SearchHistory = new List<SearchHistory>();
        WatchHistory = new List<WatchHistory>();
        WatchLaterList = new List<WatchLater>();
        Notifications = new List<Notification>();
        Views = new List<View>();
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Likes = new List<Like>();
    }
}
```

```
public class HouYun3Context : DbContext
{
    public HouYun3Context (DbContextOptions<HouYun3Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SearchHistory> SearchHistories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<View> Views { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WatchHistory> WatchHistories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WatchLater> WatchLaters { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Like>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Likes)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<View>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Views)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WatchLater>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.WatchLaterList)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WatchHistory>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.WatchHistory)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SearchHistory>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.SearchHistory)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Notifications)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);
    }
}
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Like> Likes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<View> Views { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WatchLater> WatchLaters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WatchHistory> WatchHistories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SearchHistory> SearchHistories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Video>()
            .HasMany(v => v.Likes)
            .WithOne(v => v.Video)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.VideoId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Video>()
            .HasMany(v => v.Comments)
            .WithOne(v => v.Video)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.VideoId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Video>()
            .HasMany(v => v.Views)
            .WithOne(v => v.Video)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.VideoId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Like>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Likes)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<View>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Views)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WatchLater>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.WatchLaterList)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WatchHistory>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.WatchHistory)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SearchHistory>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.SearchHistory)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Notifications)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваши модели, и настройки **DbContext**, а вообще ошибка говорит о том что запись с первичным ключом **831769c6-fc01-4203-a345-0aa12702b95e** уже существует.

Comment: добавил оба контекста и модели

Comment: `_userRepository` и `_videoRepository` используют один и тот же _экземпляр_ контекста (DbContext) или разные?

Comment: Навскидку, можно убрать `var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);` и присвоение `User = user,`. Достаточно `UserId = userId`.

Comment: _videoRepository использует HouYun3Context. _userRepository использует UserManager<User>.
когда передаю только userId, то у видео нет свойств от User, а точнее в дебаге при передаче видео свойство User = null, а все остальные свойства имеют нужные данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что проблема в том, что вы ссылку на юзера из одного контекста используете в другом контексте при добавлении видео. второй контекст не знает о том, что юзер из той же бд, просто из первого контекста. поэтому, помимо видео, сначала пытается добавить в бд этого юзера, чтоб сослаться на него в видео.

нужно либо использовать один инстанс контекста, либо добавлять во втором контектсе видео так, чтоб использовался уже имеющийся в бд юзер (преварительно его вытащить еще раз, либо как-то хитро запрос на добавление составлять).

В целом архитектура кода такая себе, настройка контекста и моделей слишком сложная. в fluent повторяете то, что уже указали в моделях. что-то странное происходит с внешним ключем:

```
class Video:
public string UserId { get; set; } //вот это стоит убрать, т.к.:
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public User User { get; set; } //в бд это уже будет string внешний ключ
```

> а точнее в дебаге при передаче видео свойство User = null, а все
> остальные свойства имеют нужные данные

- нужно использовать Include при вытаскивании из бд, либо в настройках контекста указать автоматический Include